# Extract text from html source using regular expressions java

Tags: java, regex

I like to extract text from html page using regular expressions. Here is my code:

```
String regExp="<h3 class=\"field-content\"><a[^>]*>(\\w+)</a></h3>";
    Pattern regExpMatcher=Pattern.compile(regExp,Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

    String example="<h3 class=\"field-content\"><a href=\"/humana-akcija-na-kavadarechkite-navivachi-lozari\">Проба 1</a></h3><h3 class=\"field-content\"><a href=\"/opshtina-berovo-ne-mozhe-da-sostavi-sovet-0\">Проба 2</a></h3>";
    Matcher m=regExpMatcher.matcher(example);
    while(m.find())
    {

        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

I like to get the values `Проба 1` and `Проба 2`. However I only get the first value `Проба 1`. What is my problem?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Use a HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: It is for my school project and I have to use regular expressions...

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for parsing html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If you can't use JSoup (or a real HTML parser) for this and you know there always be `<h3 whatever><a href="somethingHere"></h3>` handle it using String plain operations, not RegEx.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann from the link: *Even [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) cannot parse HTML using regular expressions.* this sentence made my day :).

Comment: @vikifor "I have to use regular expressions..." <-- no, you have to change teachers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is blasphemy to use regex + HTML. But if you really want to be cursed then here it is (you have been warned):

---

```
String regExp = "<h3 class=\"field-content\"><a[^>]*>([\\w\\s]+)</a></h3>";
                                                       ^updated part
```

Since `Проба 1` and `Проба 2` contains also spaces you need to include `\\s` to your pattern.

Comment: If you talk about blasphemy, you should not play devils advocate, now should you? :-)

Comment: It isn't blasphemy, it is sacrilege. :)

Comment: I know I am playing with fire here but there is no fun without risk  }:->

Comment: @vikifor that is one of the reasons to use tools designed for such tasks like http://jsoup.org/.

Answer (score 1):

To discover the power of the dark side, you can try this pattern:

```
<h3 class=\"field-content\"><a[^>]*>([^<]+)</a></h3>
```

Don't forget to set the UNICODE_CASE before.